# まだほかにもある what is the subject in this sentence?

Tags: particle-に

I understand this sentence means "there should be other things." But I just can't wrap my head into its structure. If I parse the sentence like:

1. ほか　＋　にも, I can't explain the に here.
2. ほかに　＋　も, then the sentence is missing the subject because ほかに (in addition) is adverb.

Please show me how to parse the structure of this sentence. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まだほかにもある doesn't contain a subject in it; まだ is an adverb, and ほかにも is an adverbial phrase.

ほかにも consists of noun ほか + case particle に + adverbial/binding particle も.

ほか is a noun, and ほかに is an adverbial phrase, "in addition" or "other than that". も is another particle adding the meaning "also" or "still". For the noun ほか to be a subject, you need to say ほかが/ほかは/ほかも, not ほかに/ほかにも/ほかには.

eg

> ほかにもまだ仕事があります。← 仕事 is the subject.
>   "There still is work, other than that." → "We have more work to do."
>
> これで全部ですか？ -- いいえ。まだほかにもあります。 ← The subject is not mentioned.
>   "Is that all?" -- "No. There still is, other than that." → "We still have more [something unmentioned]."